# numpy Layout for several arrays

Tags: python, arrays, layout, numpy

We want to layout a new array consisting of n sub-arrays.

For example: layouting three numpy arrays (x, y, z) into this result array:

```
+---+---+
|   |   |
|   | Y |
| X |   |
|   +---+
|   | Z |
+---+---+
```

We know about concatenate but we would like to use a more general approach. Missing pieces should be filled with a specifiable default value.

Comment: Unless you constrain your requirements much, much more, it seems to me you are asking for a solution to [an NP complete problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether `numpy.tile`, `numpy.expand_dims` or the like make it easier, but the following works:

```
import numpy as np 
# example arrays
x = np.ones((5,3))
# [[ 1.  1.  1.]
#  [ 1.  1.  1.]
#  [ 1.  1.  1.]
#  [ 1.  1.  1.]
#  [ 1.  1.  1.]]
y = 2*np.ones((3,3))
# [[ 2.  2.  2.]
#  [ 2.  2.  2.]
#  [ 2.  2.  2.]]
z = 3*np.ones((2,2))
# [[ 3.  3.]
#  [ 3.  3.]]

# calculate shape of resulting array
res_shape = (x.shape[0], max(x.shape[1] + y.shape[1], x.shape[1] + z.shape[1]))
# create result array and set "specifiable default value", here zero, or using np.ones as above
res = np.zeros(res_shape)

# insert subarrays into result array
res[:x.shape[0],:x.shape[1]] = x
res[:y.shape[0],x.shape[1]:x.shape[1]+y.shape[1]] = y
res[y.shape[0]:y.shape[0]+z.shape[0],x.shape[1]:x.shape[1]+z.shape[1]] = z
# array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  3.,  3.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  3.,  3.,  0.]])
```

Comment: If the solution is fine for you, please [mark the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for other users to see there is a solution. Thank you!